# [Informational] The Way Voting Works

Tags: discussion, election

This is not really a question, but an informational message. Stack Exchange (SE) uses a method of election called Single Transferable Votes (STV). AFAIK, this mechanism is recently incorporated into SE, and therefore it might be alien to some users.

Here is a very simple description of the method, taken from Wikipedia. It is rather short, and I encourage everyone (who is not familiar with STV) to take a look at it:

> Suppose a food election is conducted to determine what to serve at a party. There are 5 candidates, 3 of which will be chosen. The candidates are: *Oranges, Pears, Chocolate, Strawberries, and Sweets*. The 20 guests at the party have their ballots marked according to the table below. In this example, a second choice is needed by only some of the voters, however with a different vote distribution additional preferences may be needed.
>
> [image]
>
> First, the quota is calculated. Using the [Droop quota](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droop_quota), with 20 voters and 3 winners to be found, the number of votes required to be elected is:
>
> $\left({\mbox{20 votes cast} \over {\mbox{3 seats to fill}+1}}\right) +1 = \mbox{6 votes required}$
>
> When ballots are counted the election proceeds as follows:
>
> [image]
>
> **Result:** The winners are **Chocolate**, **Oranges** and **Strawberries**.

Last note: The counting method for SE elections is a bit different, in that it changes the quota continuously at each round. Please see [Meek's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meek%27s_method#Meek.27s_method) for more info.

Comment: ok this is great but what exactly is the value of cutting and pasting wikipedia here?

Comment: For those who want to read in context: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_transferable_vote#An_example

Comment: @Jeff: Good call ;) I just *felt* if I copy-paste it here, the chance of people reading it increases. Sorry if I made any trouble.

Comment: I don't mind. I just read it here too.

Answer (score 3):

It took me some time to figure out how the user interface at https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/election works, so here is what I learned:

- It is not a typical SE user interface where you can change your mind by clicking the vote button again.
- If you are quick, you *can* change your votes, and you can remove *some* of your votes. For example, if you have chosen A = 1st and B = 2nd, then you can select C = 2nd and your vote on B is removed. And then you can then select C = 1st, and your vote on A is removed, too. This way you can remove all of your votes, *except one*! A strange limitation, but that seems to be how it works.
- At some point your votes get frozen. If you try to change your votes, you only get a popup note that says "Your votes are too old to be changed".

**Edit:** See ["Your votes are too old to be changed"](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/913/your-votes-are-too-old-to-be-changed) for yet another feature of the system.

Comment: Nice info. I had the same issue when voting at Math.SE a few weeks ago, but I've totally forgotten this (odd) behavior.

Comment: The “some point” seems four hours after your first vote, provided that it is the same for the primary and the election phases.  See [I can't undo or change my vote in the primary election phase](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76512/i-cant-undo-or-change-my-vote-in-the-primary-election-phase) on Meta Stack Overflow about the primary phase (not the election phase).